# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open file

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

**how to Solve this error and made load data query to open my file??**

I get java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open file when trying to create statement from file. Code:

```
public class LoadData {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  File file=new File("C://Users//suriyan.s//Documents//suriyan//employees.csv");

  String filename = file.getAbsolutePath();

  System.out.println(filename);

  String tablename = "employee";

  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/college", "root", "");


  // Load the data

  String qry = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + filename + "' INTO TABLE " + tablename + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
+ " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';";

  Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

  stmt.execute(qry);


  }
}
```

Comment: Can you print out the full query and show that to us?  My guess is there is a small typo somewhere.  It looks like you are surrounding the file path in single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) of DATA LOAD INFILE:

> On Windows, specify backslashes in path names as forward slashes or doubled backslashes.

`getAbsolutePath` is returning single backslashes...

The Exception should be including the file name as it is interpreted by MySQL.

Try (remembering that "\\" is a single backslash in Java):

```
String filename = file.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
System.out.println("File: \"" + filename + "\"");  // just for debugging
```

Probably not the problem since accessing as root, but check:

> Non-LOCAL load operations read text files located on the server. For security reasons, such operations require that you have the FILE privilege.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the string query 'qry'. Try removing the semi-colon ; from the end of the string.

Comment: yes, that can be a problem depending on the driver/DB. I think MySQL is lenient , but Oracle did not accept it (long time ago).